# How to Navigate between (Pages, scenes) in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Navigation and pages aren't supported in JavaFx at my knowledge, I want to build an Application where the Views are different pages that have different Controllers, I want each page to be contained in a sort of a container inside the first scene its self, at this point I can't get a clear solution how to realize this, what should i do to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this library which is very helpful, I could realize the navigation/pagination pattern all by respecting MVC http://www.zenjava.com/2011/10/25/views-within-views-controllers-within-controllers/.
Resolved!